# How to access the outer this from jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

out of curiosity is there a way to access `this.color` from the `paint` function?

```
function Foo(color)
{
    this.color = color;
    this.paint = function paint()
    {
       $("select").each(function(idx, el)
        {
            $(el).css("background", color); // OK
            // $(el).css("background", this.color); // this.color is undefined
        })
    }
}

new Foo("red").paint();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var that = this;
function (idx, el) {
    // access what used to be this.color as that.color
}
```

Comment: a further question: is this what is called "a closure"?

Comment: @Guandalino Yes, this is a closure.

Comment: @squixy `this` always refers to the current context so if you save the outer context to a variable named `that` you can access elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I don't know what context is in second function, I mean what points `this` on in second case?

Comment: @squixy Whatever the context is of the second function. By default this is the scope that the function is called in, but it can be manually set with [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or similar.